# Python : Multiple Inheritance : Why is instance variable of super's super class is not accessible?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, instance-variables, superclass

This is the code I am trying to execute, in `Line 1` originally it was `super().super().__init__()` which wasn't working (giving out error).

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1=5

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2=10

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var3=20
        super().__init__() ## Line 1

c=C()
print(c.var1)
```

EDIT - When I tried printing the variable of class A using object of class B it works fine

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1=5

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2=10
        super().__init__()

b=B()
print(b.var1)
```

My question is why is `c.var1` not giving out right output? (in both the cases, `super().__init__()` and `super().super().__init__()` and how can I access it?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing an argument to `c = C(<class instance here>)` when invoking?  Otherwise, what's the point in expecting an argument for either class B or class C?

Comment: since the above code has a non-parameterized constructor, when invoking the constructor, we are not required to pass any arguments. Now point in expecting argument for class B or class C is that I am assuming that since the variables declared in the constructors are public and not private, so when the class is being inherited their instance variables should be accessible. is it what you're asking me ? :)

Comment: More or less, yes that answers my question - Interesting.  I'm new to Python so thanks for explaining.

Comment: We're all here to learn from each other :) thanks for asking a wonderful question for further explanation. And yes just since I am also new like you I always try to help other developers in building their reputation. :) So thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little test for you that will help;

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 5
        print("In A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 10
        print("In B")

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var3 = 20
        print("In C")
        super().__init__() ## Line 1

c = C()
```

will print;

```
In C
In B
```

but if you add a call in B to the constructor of A;

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 5
        print("In A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 10
        print("In B")
        super().__init__()

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var3 = 20
        print("In C")
        super().__init__() ## Line 1

c = C()
```

You get what you would expect;

```
In C
In B
In A
```

and this...

```
print(c.var1)
5
```

Comment: wonderful. Can you please also help me understand why I get the error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'super'` when I use ` super().super().__init__()`

Comment: As a clarifying point here - the same way that `C`'s init function doesn't call `B`'s automatically, `B` doesn't call `A`'s init unless it's explicitly configured to do so.

Comment: @AshUpadhyay -- Honestly, I've never tried it that way -- nor can I think of a reason why I would.

Comment: No problem @SteveJ thanks for the wonderful explanation. :) Upvoting and accepting your answer.